# Why the Debug.Assert show the error message even if the Length is 1 all the time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assert

```
private GameObject GetDoorShaderPrefab()
    {
        string[] shieldPrefab = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(c_doorShieldFxLocked);
        Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length != 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
        string shieldGuid = shieldPrefab[0];
        string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(shieldGuid);
        GameObject prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
        Debug.Assert(prefab != null, "Expected prefab to load");
        return prefab;
    }
```

I used a break point on the line :

```
Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length != 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
```

The Length of shieldPrefab is all the time 1 but it's still showing the error message "Expected exactly 1 shield like this..."

The method GetDoorShaderPrefab is being called many times in other place in the script. But each time the Length is 1 and it keep showing the error message.

Comment: According to the documentation the message shows if the condition is false.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Right, So why if the Length is 1 and the condition is if it's not 1 != 1 then why it's showing the message ? The condition is : shieldPrefab.Length != 1 so if it's not 1 show the message but the Length is 1

Comment: Exactly  the condition has to be FALSE for it to show! So var myCondition = shieldPrefab.Length != 1..... what is the value of that statement? myCondition is true if the length is NOT 1 but it will be false if the length is 1

Comment: Yes it's a bit confusing first time. I think that I used this for checking something before completed the script.  Then the condition/s was false.  And now it's working fine the length should be 1 but it wasn't before. So I also got confused and also forgot to remove this line or change the condition after the script was working fine.

Comment: But still it's a bit confusing because if you forgot to remove the line or to change the condition it will be false even if it's true in the script flow.

Comment: Think of Debug.Assert as a cop that makes sure the conditions are met... if the condition is not met that it yells out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your condition should be `== 1`
so:

```
Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length == 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
```

The message is displayed when the condition is `false`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Debug_Assert_System_Boolean_System_String_):

> **Assert(Boolean, String)**
>
> Checks for a condition; if the condition is `false`, outputs a specified message and displays a message box that shows the call stack.

The idea is that the asserts checks some conditions and it will only complain is your assertion is wrong.

To remember it easily, the condition and text should tell you the same, not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netframework-4.8) Debug.Assert shows the message if the condition is **false**....

Therefore when you say "shieldPrefab.Length != 1" this is always false because the Length is always 1.

If you want to check if the Length is **not** 1 you need to apply the opposite:

```
Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length == 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
```

Comment: Yes, assert means to ensure something is true (or enforce strongly an idea or statement), therefore you assert that the condition is true, not that the condition is false. A false result means that your assert has failed.

Comment: Right, I got it in the end. A bit slow but got it now.